# Adding text at the start of a p element

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this paragraph:

```
<p id="paragraph">Hello World!</p>
```

I want to add "Hello StackOverflow! " at the start of the paragraph.

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML += "Hello StackOverflow! "
```

Adding the above line didn't work as it adds the content to the end of the paragraph, not the start.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a template string to easily do this:

```js
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = `Hello StackOverflow! ${document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML}`
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previews text in a variable and then update the `innerHTML`

```js
const el = document.getElementById('paragraph')
const prevTxt = el.innerHTML

el.innerHTML = 'Hello StackOverflow! ' + prevTxt
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! although I think you meant `const prevTxt = el.innerHTML`, not `const prevTxt = element.innerHTML`.

Comment: A little error I didn't notice.... yep you are right!